# Form not taking data from dynamically added fields

Tags: html, angularjs

I am attempting to create an expandable form to create on/off instructions that a user can submit times for in pairings, so my HTML defaults with one pair and the user can use a button to add additional pairs, but when i submit the form angular is only reading the first pairing, can someone point out what I am missing here? Am I appending in the extra fields improperly?

HTML

```
<div class="timing">
  <form class="timingSelect" action="index.html" method="post">
    <div class="inputField">
      <div class="form-group">
        On: <input type="number" ng-model="recipe.on1" value="" step=".1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        oz: <input type="number" ng-model="recipe.oz1" value="" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        Off: <input type="number" ng-model="recipe.off1" value="" step='.1'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <input type="submit" ng-click="createRecipe(recipe)" value="Generate Recipe"> -->
  </form>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="createRecipe(recipe)">Submit</button>


</div>
<button type="button" class="next" name="button" ng-click="addColumn()">+</button>
```

JS:

```
    app.controller('CreateRecipeController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'DashFactory', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, DashFactory){
  console.log("entered Create Recipe controller");

  var columnCount = 1;

  $scope.addColumn = function addColumn(){
    columnCount++;
    console.log('attempting to create column');
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.className = "inputField";
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");
    var d2 = document.createElement("div");
    d2.className = "form-group"
    var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
    i.setAttribute('type',"number");
    i.setAttribute('ng-model',"recipe.on"+columnCount);
    i.setAttribute('value',"");

    var d3 = document.createElement("div");
    d3.className = "form-group"
    var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
    s.setAttribute('type',"number");
    s.setAttribute('ng-model',"recipe.oz"+columnCount);
    s.setAttribute('value',"");
    s.setAttribute('readonly','readonly')

    var d4 = document.createElement("div");
    d4.className = "form-group"
    var t = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
    t.setAttribute('type',"number");
    t.setAttribute('ng-model',"recipe.off"+columnCount);
    t.setAttribute('value',"");

    d.appendChild(f);
    f.appendChild(d2);
    f.appendChild(d3);
    f.appendChild(d4);
    d2.appendChild(i);
    d3.appendChild(s);
    d4.appendChild(t)

    document.getElementsByClassName('timingSelect')[0].appendChild(d);
  }

  $scope.createRecipe = function(recipe){
    console.log('recieved recipe data', recipe);
    DashFactory.createRecipe(recipe)
  }


}
]);
```

Comment: AngularJS directives, such as `ng-model`, added by DOM manipulation, will not be noticed and compiled by the AngularJS framework. In general use the `ng-repeat` directive to add elements to the template. Avoid doing DOM manipulation in controllers. DOM manipulation should only be done in directives, either core directives or custom directives.

Answer (score 0):

Great - Just move all your buttons inside your form tag like the code below

```
    <div class="timing">
      <form class="timingSelect" action="index.html" method="post">
        <div class="inputField">
          <div class="form-group">
            On: <input type="number" ng-model="recipe.on1" value="" step=".1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            oz: <input type="number" ng-model="recipe.oz1" value="" readonly="readonly">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            Off: <input type="number" ng-model="recipe.off1" value="" step='.1'>
          </div>
        </div>
         <button type="submit" ng-click="createRecipe(recipe)">Submit</button>
         <button type="button" class="next" name="button" ng-click="addColumn()">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

And don't add another form when you append a new input field just add all your new inputs inside the existing form and try to submit it again - This might work

Thanks - Happy Coding !!

Comment: Made the changes you recommended, it still is not getting inputs form the dynamic inputs

Comment: In your click function you are passing `recipe` but you are adding a new object to the `recipe` like this `s.setAttribute('ng-model',"recipe.oz"+columnCount)` does the recipe object have this property in it or you try to add it dynamically - if so add the property in your object as null and then add it dynamically change that for all dynamic property creation - add your `$scope.recipe` in console and check whether data got binded in it at the click function